# Silverlight-like transition effects in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, microsoft-metro, transition

I have seen packages like MahApps (http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) which will allow WPF programs to have the look and feel of Metro.

I've also seen some pretty good looking Silverlight programs created with that Metro theme in mind. For example, when you click a button a panel will slide/transition out over the time span of about a quarter of a second (I don't mean just a simple fade in, I mean the panel physically moving across the screen until it is at full size). My understanding is that this is achieved with storyboards.

My question is whether it is possible in a WPF application to do these sort of transition / visual effects? Or is it something that is strictly in the realm of Silverlight?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to prevent you from doing these transitions in WPF.